# Angular universal send component as HTML

Tags: angular

I've an application with Angular Universal and express server which is working fine. I am able to send HTML emails from this application using smtp server and nodemailer. I am very new to angular universal.

I want to have this functionality - When user clicks 'send mail' button, an email should be sent to user with same page (view he is currently viewing) as email content. For this, in nodemailer, I have field called HTML, where I need to send compiled HTML from the component. From what I read, renderModuleFactory seems to be the method I need, but I don't exactly know how to use it, and I couldn't find much documentation about it.

Here's my server.ts -

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as express from 'express';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ServerAppModule } from './app/server-app.module';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { ROUTES } from './routes';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
//const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const cache = new Map();

enableProdMode();
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
const baseUrl = `http://localhost:${port}`;

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: ServerAppModule
}));

// app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
//   options.bootstrap = ServerAppModule;
//   let template = readFileSync(options.req.html, { encoding: 'utf8'});
//   const opts = {
//     document: template,
//     url: options.req.url,
//  };

// renderModuleFactory(options, opts)
//   .then(html => callback(null, html));
// });

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src');

app.use('/', express.static('dist', {index: false}));

ROUTES.forEach((route: string) => {
  app.get(route, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.time(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
    res.render('../dist/index', {
     req: req,
     res: res
    });
    console.timeEnd(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at ${baseUrl}`);
});

const ngExpressEngine = (setupOptions) => {
  return (filePath, options, callback) => {
    if (!cache.has(filePath)) {
      const content  = readFileSync(filePath).toString();
      cache.set(filePath, content);
    }
    renderModuleFactory(setupOptions.bootstrap, {
      document: cache.get(filePath),
      url: options.req.url
    })
    .then(htmlString => {
      callback(null, htmlString);
    });
  }
}

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'trytry@gmail.com',
        pass: 'trytry',
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com', 
        ssl: true
    }
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: 'trytry@gmail.com',
    to: 'abc@xyz.com',
    subject: 'Test Mailer',
    //html: 'This is where I need to have the contents of the page in HTML',
};

app.options('/sendmail', (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.post('/sendmail', (req, res) => {  
    let path = req.body.filePath; 
    console.log('req.url = ', req.url);
    console.log('sendmail called in server');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8000'); 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    // Here, I want to call a function (ngExpressEngine()?), which will generate HTML from the component, 
    //and in the .then of that async action, I will call this transporter.sendMail function.
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    });
});
```

I am not having a clear picture on use of ngExpressEngine.

One questions I have is - 
- In this part - 'url: options.req.url', what should be passed as url, is it the req.url, i.e. '/sendmail' or the url of the view that I am trying to send?

Can someone help me see how I can compile HTML of the component to send it in email? 
Thanks in advance.